# bind_quoted does not create a binding inside a def

Tags: macros, elixir

`bind_quoted` doesn't seem to work for me.  Here is an example that doesn't use `bind_quoted`, and it works as expected:

```
defmodule Animals do

  defmacro dog do
    x = 4 

    quote do
      def go do
        IO.puts unquote(x)
      end
    end

  end

end

defmodule Test do
  require Animals
  Animals.dog  #inject the definition of go() into the Test module
end
```

In iex:

```
iex(10)> c "a.exs"
warning: redefining module Animals (current version defined in memory)
  a.exs:1

warning: redefining module Test (current version defined in memory)
  a.exs:15

[Test, Animals]

iex(11)> Test.go  
4
:ok

iex(12)>
```

But the [bind_quoted docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html) say:

> ...the :bind_quoted option is recommended every time one desires to
>   inject a value into the quote.

Okay, let's be conformant:

```
defmodule Animals do

  defmacro dog do
    x = 4 

    quote bind_quoted: [x: x] do
      def go do
        IO.puts x
      end
    end

  end

end

defmodule Test do
  require Animals
  Animals.dog  #inject go() into the Test module
end
```

Compiling in iex:

```
iex(10)> c "a.exs"
warning: redefining module Animals (current version defined in memory)
  a.exs:1

warning: redefining module Test (current version defined in memory)
  a.exs:15

warning: variable "x" does not exist and is being expanded to "x()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  a.exs:17


== Compilation error in file a.exs ==
** (CompileError) a.exs:17: undefined function x/0 
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
** (CompileError)  compile error
    (iex) lib/iex/helpers.ex:183: IEx.Helpers.c/2
iex(10)>
```

The relevant message in the error report is:

```
warning: variable "x" does not exist
```

Why not?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, yes. That's how it would work. But the `def` call itself is a macro, so you would still need to use `unquote` inside it. If you directly quoted `IO.puts`, it would have worked without issues.

Here's a slightly modified version of your code demonstrating it:

```ex
defmodule Animals do
  defmacro dog do
    x = 4

    quote(bind_quoted: [xx: x]) do
      IO.puts(xx)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  require Animals

  def go do
    Animals.dog
  end
end
```

---

Now back to your implementation; I bound `x` to `xx` in this example to explicitly show you that if you try to unquote `x` here (instead of `xx`) it will throw a compilation error:

```ex
defmodule Animals do
  defmacro dog do
    x = 4

    quote(bind_quoted: [xx: x]) do
      def go do
        IO.puts(unquote(xx))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `if you try to unquote x here (instead of xx) it will throw a compilation error`--
Hmm...that's interesting. The way `bind_quoted` works is much trickier than presented in the docs. I really don't understand why `bind_quoted` doesn't just replace all instances of the keyword found in the ast.  I guess the rule is: `bind_quoted` will not create a binding inside a nested macro, e.g. `def` in this case; and a def block can only see bindings in the immediately enclosing do block, hence the reason the def's do block can see xx but not x.